# How to compile Torque 2D with TGB Platformer Kit on Mac OS X 10.7?

Tags: torque

I'm trying to recompile Torque-2d (or even Torque) with the TGB Platformer kit on Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) using Xcode and it just doesn't compile. I tried following the instructions from the developer but it didn't work, it complains about some functions that are deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

probably too late but the setting for it to work is:
SDK = MACOSX 10.4
compiler = GCC4.0 (will not work with 4.2, yet 4.0 is not available in newer xcode4 without hacking)
C language dialect = C99